# Using Apache Lucene to parse large PDF files

Tags: parsing, pdf, lucene, pdfbox

I am trying to find out the best way to search/parse a set of large pdf file. I am currently using PDFBox to convert my PDF files to text files. I am then using Lucene to index these text files and search for information. I am facing some problems using this approach. ( Note that I am using both these technologies at a very basic level just to see what they can do) .

Consider the following line from my PDF file that gives the Grand total of all the columns. Each column contains a pair of values whose total is displayed as follows.

```
    Grand Total  $3,148.06 $484.80 $13.07 $8.90 $0.00 $69.90 $0.00 $0.00
                 $10.00    $5.15   $25.60 $0.00 $2.69 $0.00  $0.00 $0.00 $3,768.17
```

When I convert my pdf file to a text file using TextStripper from PDFBox, The above line from the pdf file is converted to the following text in the text file.

```
    58.20$3,148.06 $484.80 $13.07 $0.00 $0.00 $0.00Grand Total $8.90 $69.90$10.00 $5.15 $25.60 $0.00 $2.69 $0.00 $0.00 $0.00 $3,768.17
```

As it can be seen from the text file above, the data is scattered around the Grand Total label. Therefore, it becomes difficult to retrieve the Grand total information as the indentation from the PDF file is not maintained in the text file.

I would therefore like to know if there is a way to convert the PDF file to a text file such that the text file maintains the indentations/format from the PDF file. I would also like to know if Lucene is a good idea to achieve my objective or is there a simpler and faster way to retrieve information from a set of large PDF files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/). (Generally when people extract data from PDFs into Lucene, they use Tika.)

Is there an easier way? Solr has [strong integration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) with Tika, which should make it quite easy to index PDF documents. (Solr is a wrapper around Lucene.)

Comment: My requirement is to be able to search for a label in the PDF file (Grand total in my case) and to be able to retrieve the corresponding values for a label. From what I understand, I will be able to easily search for the labels I am interested in using Tika, Solr etc and identify the documents that contain this label. However, will it be possible to easily retrieve the actual value (value of Grand total in my case) corresponding to the label using this approach?

Comment: @bot: you can certainly get a field from each document which matches your query. The relevant question is: will Tika be able to parse my PDF correctly? to which I think the only answer is: try it out and see.